# Unregister combobox SelectedIndexChanged event before AddIn shutdown

Tags: asp.net, winforms, vsto, word-automation

I am developing a MS Word 2010 AddIn, in which I have a combobox which updates a class property when it is changed:

```
private void comboboxFloweringStart_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Globals.ThisAddIn.currentTaxon.FloweringStart = (short)this.comboboxFloweringStart.SelectedIndex;
}
```

This class is serialized on shutdown (`ThisAddIn_Shutdown` event handler). The combobox is located on `Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane taxonMarkupPanel` based on the user control `TaxonPanel myTaxonPanel` which I designed.

The problem is that at some point before the shutdown event fires, the `SelectedIndexChanged` event on the combobox fires and resets the value to 0, and this is the value that is serialized. I know that I could use `SelectionChangeCommitted` instead of `SelectedIndexChanged`, but I do at times set the index in code, and the event should fire in these cases too.

The CustomTaskPane does not have a close event that I could use to unsubscribe the event handler and I don't know the order of events when a VSTO is closed. Is there some other event I could subscribe to, or some other way that I can unsubscribe the `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler when the custom task pane / user control is closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should *subscribe* to the `DocumentBeforeClose` event of the *Application*, and/or `Close` event of the  *Document*.

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Word.Application app = this.Application;
    Word.Document doc = app.ActiveDocument;
    app.DocumentBeforeClose += new Word.ApplicationEvents4_DocumentBeforeCloseEventHandler(ThisAddIn_DocumentBeforeClose);
    ((Word.DocumentEvents2_Event)doc).Close += new Word.DocumentEvents2_CloseEventHandler(ActiveDocument_Close);
}

private void ThisAddIn_DocumentBeforeClose(Word.Document doc, ref bool cancel)
{
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format ("Document {0} is closing.", doc.Name));
}

private void ActiveDocument_Close()
{
    MessageBox.Show("Active document is closing.");
}
```